# Alternative to "fc -s" in zsh?

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh

In `bash`, I had a handy alias:

```
alias r="fc -s"
```

Which just repeated last command. Same as `!!`. I am now used to it (muscle memory), but I can't seem to figure out how to recreate the alias. `fc` doesn't have `-s` option in `zsh`. How can I bind `!!` behavior to `r`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command

```
fc -e -
```

should do what you want. This is a little bit tricky, because `fc -e [edit-cmd]` usually lets you edit tha last command with an editor. But if the `[edit-cmd]` equals `-`, no editor is invoked and the command is executed immediately.

But you won't need an alias for that, because the command `r` is already defined in the *Z shell*:

```
$ which r
r: shell built-in command
```

And what does it do? The *zshbuiltins* man page does know it:

> `r`       Same as `fc -e -`.

Comment: What's bizarre is that there's no documentation about what `fc -e` *actually* does!

Comment: @Marco: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I've given a summery what `fc -e -` does in my own words. The documentation is in `man zshbuiltins`: _fc [ -e ename ] [ -LI ] [ -m match ] [ old=new ... ] [ first [ last ] ] (...) Otherwise the editor program ename is invoked on a file containing these history events. (...)_

Comment: @mpy Sorry, that comment was not directed at you! The `man` documentation (`zshall` for example) does not explain what `fc -e` does, which was frustrating. It mentions `fc -e`, but doesn't say what it does.

Comment: BTW, you have *not* given a summary of what `fc -e` does -- you've only said that it "should do what you want".